# Oracle Apex paste from clipboard into textarea

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex

All I want if I have text on my clipboard then pressing that button it should write the content to the textarea. It should be compatible with IE/Firefox.

[image]

I should do it with javascript. Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Click on the textarea and then click on the `Edit` menu button and then on the `Paste` menu item. Or right-click and select `Paste`. Or `Ctrl-V`. Or whatever action your device takes. Granting arbitrary access to the clipboard is a security risk and browsers do not allow it. Firefox has the [`ClipboardEvent API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ClipboardEvent) but that is related to user-initiated cut/copy/paste events and is not unlimited access to the clipboard. You are likely to find that what you want is not possible due to the possibility of malicious abuse.

Comment: @MT0 Is there any chance maybe to solve this problem by triggering CTRL + V? I mean if there would be a display message for the user on the page to press CTRL + V so it would paste all the data to an item on the application. After it's done I can do with that data whatever I want - like save it to the database...

Comment: `Ctrl+V` is just the keyboard shortcut for the paste action from the menu (you should be able to see that by pressing `Alt+E` to open the browser's edit menu and see that next to the paste option is the keyboard shortcut); if you want the contents of the clipboard into the textarea then giving it the focus and pasting it (via whatever method; i.e. mouse, keyboard or gesture) is the answer and you don't need a button for it. Just add a text instruction to paste the data into the textbox and let the user work out how to perform that action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible without ActiveXObject in modern browsers.

I found a way to do it if you want to upload data for example from .csv:

1. Create a batch script which opens your file and copy its content with clip command.
2. Once it is done then open the page (textarea can be hidden - under a div or anything)
3. Ask the user to press copy paste command (CTRL+V) so it is going to paste the content to the hidden textarea then you can proceed it by triggering CTRL + V.